# How can I list the search providers in GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome-shell

When I search for something in GNOME Shell by pressing the <kbd>super</kbd> key (or pressing the Activities button in the top left corner of the screen), there are multiple search providers that give results. Here are some that I've noticed:

- Files (nautilus)
- Software (App center)
- Characters (GNOME Characters)
- Settings
- Web (epiphany)

How can I find a list of all the search providers on my system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open *Settings* app and navigate to *Search*. You can see a list of search providers in the interface there, and you can enable or disable the providers you want. You also re-order them by dragging and dropping them from the handle on the left!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You can find a list of files that represents search providers by running this command:

```
$ ls -1 -d /usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/* /snap/*/*/usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/* /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/*
/snap/snap-store/959/usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/org.gnome.Software-search-provider.ini
/usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/gnome-terminal-search-provider.ini
/usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/org.gnome.Calculator-search-provider.ini
/usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/org.gnome.Calendar.search-provider.ini
/usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/org.gnome.Characters.search-provider.ini
/usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/org.gnome.Contacts.search-provider.ini
/usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/org.gnome.Epiphany.SearchProvider.ini
/usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/org.gnome.Gnote.search-provider.ini
/usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/org.gnome.Nautilus.search-provider.ini
/usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/org.gnome.Settings.search-provider.ini
/usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/org.gnome.Software-search-provider.ini
/usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/seahorse-search-provider.ini
/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/app.drey.Dialect.SearchProvider.ini
```

If you want just the file names (representing the app names) without the paths, run:

```
$ for i in /usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/* /snap/*/*/usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/* /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/* ; do basename "$i" ; done
gnome-terminal-search-provider.ini
org.gnome.Calculator-search-provider.ini
org.gnome.Calendar.search-provider.ini
org.gnome.Characters.search-provider.ini
org.gnome.Contacts.search-provider.ini
org.gnome.Epiphany.SearchProvider.ini
org.gnome.Gnote.search-provider.ini
org.gnome.Nautilus.search-provider.ini
org.gnome.Settings.search-provider.ini
org.gnome.Software-search-provider.ini
seahorse-search-provider.ini
org.gnome.Software-search-provider.ini
app.drey.Dialect.SearchProvider.ini
```

Comment: How do you add to that list?

Comment: @bvargo You would need to program a search provider, see [this guide](https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/tutorials/search-provider.html)